# Java program not able to exectue nextLine() properly

Tags: java

When I run my program instead of reading the string and storing it in tempAddress my program simply prints the next line before I enter input. Using next works for the first two because I am only using one word but the third one encompasses multiple words so need something else and through my research I found nextLine() was the answer but I am not able to get it to work as others have, thanks in advance.

```
System.out.println("Enter Employee First Name: ");
String tempFirstName = input.next();
employeesArray[i].setFirstName(tempFirstName);

System.out.println("Enter Employee Last Name: ");
String tempLastName = input.next();
employeesArray[i].setLastName(tempLastName);

System.out.println("Enter Employee Address: ");
String tempAddress = input.nextLine();
employeesArray[i].setAddress(tempAddress);

System.out.println("Enter Employee Title: ");
String tempTitle = input.next();
employeesArray[i].setTitle(tempTitle);
```

Comment: What do you expect `nextLine()` to do and what are you finding "not able to get it to work"?

Comment: Expecting it to read input from user... as stated above "my program simply prints the next line before I enter input"

Comment: This code works for me `System.out.println("Enter Employee Address: ");
     String tempAddress = input.nextLine();
     System.out.println("tempAddress : " + tempAddress);`

Comment: It will be explain what exactly and how it isn't working for you. The method is doing its job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Scanner tokenizes the input by default using whitespace. Using next() method of scanner returns the first token before the space and the pointer stays there. Using nextLine() returns the whole line and then moves the pointer to the next line.

The reason your nextLine() was not behaving fine was because, your previous input for employee last name using next() cause the pointer to stay in the line hence, when you reach the point to take the employee address using nextLine(), the pointer returns remainder of the previous input next() which was obviously empty (when supplied one word as input to next()). Assume you entered two words separated by space for last name, the next() will store the first word in last name field and pointer waits after first token before second token and as soon as you reach nextLine() pointer returns the second token and moves to new line.

The solution is to execute nextLine() after reading the input for last name to make sure that your pointer is in new line waiting for input for address.

I updated my code by inserting a input.nextLine() there to make sure that scanner input is consumed and pointer is moved to the next line.

```
    System.out.println("Enter Employee First Name: ");
    String tempFirstName = input.next();
    employeesArray[i].setFirstName(tempFirstName);

    System.out.println("Enter Employee Last Name: ");
    String tempLastName = input.next();
    employeesArray[i].setLastName(tempLastName);

    //feed this to move the scanner to next line
    input.nextLine(); 

    System.out.println("Enter Employee Address: ");
    String tempAddress = input.nextLine();
    employeesArray[i].setAddress(tempAddress);

    System.out.println("Enter Employee Title: ");
    String tempTitle = input.next();
    employeesArray[i].setTitle(tempTitle);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: this works, but what if you don't want to have ' ' (space) in your input? you would have to make a whole thing just for that.

Comment: I have updated the answer, as well as update the code with a fix that addresses his issue. @789 and tungd cheers for pointing out the issue.

Comment: @789 yes, provided last name is always one token - which is in nature. nextLine() will move it to the new line, regardless.

Comment: @user2383106 glad it helped. upvote the question as it was useful and I learned from answering it ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you have `input.next()`, it reads the input, but not the `newline` character, it leaves it in the input stream. `input.nextLine()` ends with a `newline` character. So when `input.nextLine()` is executed, it stops without taking any input because it already got the `newline` (`\n`) char from the input stream.

Solution: read the `newline` before you execute `inupt.nextLine()`:

```
System.out.println("Enter Employee Address: ");
input.next();//read the newline char - and don't store it, we don't need it.
String tempAddress = input.nextLine();
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/3013996

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I have accepted other answer as it was first, but made sure to upvote your answer and comments